# how to validate input field which contains object

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, nebular

how can I check that the required input field is not empty, formControl cannot read the object...

```js
  public discountParamsForm = new FormGroup({
     name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     type: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     status: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     value: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^([0-9]{1,2}){1}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/),
       Validators.min(1), Validators.max(100)]),
     dateInput: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
     categorySelect: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
```

```html
<input formControlName="dateInput" fullWidth type="text" [(ngModel)]="dateRange"
           nbInput placeholder="{{pickDateUI}}" [nbDatepicker]="datepicker">
    <nb-rangepicker (rangeChange)="onDateChange($event)" format="yyyy-MM-dd" #datepicker></nb-rangepicker>
```

[console.log for value and discountparamsform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjMlF.png)

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBmVv.png)

Comment: When using `required` then your input can't be empty and throw error . And what do you mean by :  field cannot read the object... , mean by this **....**

Comment: @Rana check screenshots please, dateInput contains object, I think formGroup cannot validate objects, so I need solution.

Comment: Please refer to => [Defining custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators)

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here, you are looking at the form object itself. You can see on the image of the console, the entire form is `INVALID`.

If you want to see if one field in a form you can use the get method.

in your component

```js
this.discountParamsForm.get('name');
```

this returns a FormControl object, and has values such as valid/invalid and many other use full indicators.

you can add a getter method in your component to check this in your html.

```js
get name() {
  return this.discountParamsForm.get('name');
}
```

```html
<input [ngClass]="{'my-invalid-class': name.invalid}"
```

since we have a getter method we dont need to check the form directly and we can easily access the control inside the parent form.

Answer (score -1):

**never, never** use in the same tag `[(ngModel)]` and `formControlName`

Well, use a [custom Validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators).

```
discountParamsForm = new FormGroup({
    ...
    dateInput: new FormControl('', this.validatorRange()),
})

validatorRange(){
  return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
     if (!control.value.start)
         return {error:'start date is mandatory'}
     if (!control.value.end)
         return {error:'end date is mandatory'}
  }
}
```

See that the control is always an object with properties "start" and "end" -so always has value, so in the custom validator we check if this properties has value or not-